# How to use \textcircled in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

How can I use `\textcircled` from the textcomp package in the text of an .rmd document?

I have tried using `\( \textcircled{r} \)` and `\textcircled{r}`. I would like to make html_document

```
---
title: "my doc"
header-includes: 
  \usepackage{textcomp}
output:
  html_document:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: no
---

\( \textcircled{r} \)
\textcircled{r}
```

Comment: Though I haven't tested it (do you get any errors? if yes, please include them), I think your `\usepackage` needs to be preceded by a bullet, as in (indented) `- \usepackage{textcomp}`. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-logo.html#latex-logo for discussion of `header-includes`.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but I will also try it out with a bulletpoint 
EDIT: no changes after adding the `-`

Comment: I think the real problem lies in that I am trying to use latex constructs in html

Comment: I wasn't certain (no time at the moment to test), just thought I'd mention it just-in-case. I used similar LaTeX constructs just like that (direct backslashes) in Rmd docs on a regular basis, so the premise is fine. I haven't tried that package and that command, though. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274574/82137 suggests that it supports single digits (perhaps not letters?), and provides a `tikz` alternative `\mycircled{r}` function.

Comment: this would be a clever solution if it worked, but then I get into the problem where I'm not sure how to write custom commands in the `header-includes` section :P

Comment: If your goal is to create an HTML document you can use unicode and inline R `r knitr::asis_output("\U24C7")`, though I'm not sure of the impact this will have if you also want to create a PDF.

Comment: John-Henry, I believe you can take all six lines from that other answer (starting with `\usepackage` and ending with `}`) and just add them prepended with "4-spaces, hyphen, space" immediately under your `header-includes:`. Alternatively (and perhaps more idiomatically), you can create a LaTeX file (e.g., `preamble.tex`) and include it with `in_header:` (though under `pdf_document`), as described at https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-preamble.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an `html_document`, `knitr::asis_output("\U24C7")` will work